# Closed, open and non-empty subset of $\Bbb R^n$ equals $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed , open and non-empty . Prove that $A = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. Theorem: a topological space $X$ is connected iff it has exactly two closed and open subsets, $\emptyset$  and $X$.

Answer (score 1):

How much do you know about compact sets? Starting with a point $x_0 \in A$ there exists an open ball $B(x_0,r) \subset A$ since $A$ is open. Let $R = \sup\{r > 0 \mid B(x_0,r) \subset A\}$. Since this set is nonempty $R > 0$ exists. If $R = \infty$ then $A = \mathbb R^n$. Otherwise if $R < \infty$ use the fact that $A$ is both closed and open to show that

1) the closed ball $B[x_0,R]$ is contained in $A$, and

2) there exists $\epsilon > 0$ so that the open ball $B(x_0,R+\epsilon)$ is contained in $A$.

Derive a contradiction and deduce $R = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

First show the case $n=1$ (arguing with $\sup$ and $\inf$ of suitable sets). Then for general $n$ assume otherwise and pick $a\in A$, $b\notin A$ and consider the line $\cong \mathbb R$ through these two points.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are saying, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction if $A$ is open and closed and $A$ is not $\mathbb R^n$ then $\mathbb R^n$ is not connected since $A \cup A^c$ is a disjoint union. This is a contradiction since $\mathbb R^n$ is connected.